# How To Allow 2 Roblox Players To Jump On A Part And Both Get A Win

Tags: lua, wait, debouncing

My Problem is that when I try to script what I listed in the Title, it always gives a win to only one player when they both jump at the same time. I just need help to fix this and only give 1 win to each player without a cooldown. So, if anyone can help, please do.

I tried adding a debounce into my script and that didn't work. It also had a cooldown which was scripted as wait (1). I tried this with and without the cooldown and it only gave a win to one player with it on and gave 3 wins to each player with it off.

This is the code I used

```
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)   
    if db == true then

        if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
            db = false  
            local plr = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
            plr.leaderstats.Wins.Value = plr.leaderstats.Wins.Value + 1
            db = true
        end
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a array and insert the player name whenever they touch the part. But before you insert you need to search the array to see if the player is already in there. Insert the player name if not in the list and the size of array is less than 2.

```lua
-- for example
-- global array
local winners = {}

-- after the humanoid check is valid you can do something like this
if #winners < 2 and not winners.find(playerName) then 
    winners.insert(playerName);
    -- increment player leaderboard here
end
```

Comment: I've never done an array before. It wont give 1 win to each player that touches it.